# Conditions for non-negativity of 2nd-order polynomial with several variables

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Sorry, if I forget to specify something, I am an engineer and we are usually not very specific when we try to talk math. I am familiar with positive definite matrices and basic linear algebra. I am interested in scalar valued non-negative 2nd-order polynomials $p(x)$ with several variables $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, expressed as

\begin{equation}
p(x)
=
x^T A x + b^T x
\geq 0 \ \forall x
\end{equation}

with the matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and the vector $b \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. I am interested in the conditions for the non-negativity of the polynomial. For $b=0$, I know that $A$ has to be positive semidefinite. But for $b \neq 0$, what are the conditions for $A$ and $b$?

My attempt is to complete the square, which, defining $(A+A^T)y = b$, gives

\begin{equation}
p(x) 
=
(x+y)^TA(x+y) - y^T Ay \geq 0 \ \forall x \ . 
\end{equation}

From this perspective, I think that $A$ has to be positive semidefinite and $-y^T Ay = - b^T(A+A^T)^{-T}A(A+A^T)^{-1}b \geq 0$ is the coupling condition which $A$ and $b$ have to fulfill. Is there any other condition that I might be missing? My perspective is still somehow bizarre, since, if I restrict myself to positive definite and symmetric $A$, then $(A+A^T)^{-T}A(A+A^T)^{-1}$ is positive definite and there exists no $b$ (besides ($b=0$) to ensure non-negativity. Am I doing something wrong? Thanks!

**EDIT (after Hagen's answer)**

I prefer to edit this question, instead of creating a new one. If we extend the polynomial by a constant $c$ as

$$
q(x) = x^T A x + b^T x + c \geq 0 \quad \forall x
$$

for a general (not necessarily symmetric or even diagonalizable) real matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, the vector $b \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and the real constant $c \in \mathbb{R}$, **what are the conditions on $A,b$ and $c$?**

1) As Hagen pointed out, if $c=0$, then $b=0$ is necessary and the condition on $A$ is positive semidefiniteness.

2) For $c>0$, the square might be completed as above with $b = (A+A^T)y$ as

$$
q(x)
=
(x+y)^TA(x+y) + (c-y^TAy) \geq 0 \quad \forall x 
$$

which is fulfilled if $A$ is positive semidefinite and a $b$ exists fulfilling $c \geq y^T A y = b^T (A+A^T)^{-T}A(A+A^T)^{-1}b > 0$. But here I am not able to see, under which conditions for $A$ such $b$ even exists, since, e.g., the matrix

$$
A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

is non-diagonalizable, positive definite (eigenvalues $\{1,1\}$), its symmetric part $A+A^T$ is invertible (eigenvalues $\{5,-1\}$), but the matrix $(A+A^T)^{-T}A(A+A^T)^{-1}$ is negative definite (eigenvalues $\left\{-\frac{1}{5},-\frac{1}{5}\right\}$) such that no $b$ exist for this exemplary $A$.

**So, what are the full conditions on $A,b$ and $c$ such that $q(x) \geq 0 \forall x$?**

**Last edit**

Sorry, I had the property of positive definiteness wrong in my head. The exemplary $A$ given above is NOT positive definite, since its symmetric part is indefinite.

I just realized that for homogeneous polynomials $x^T A x$ only the symmetric part of $A$ is relevant, i.e., we have to consider only symmetric $A$ (assumed from this point on). If $A$ is symmetric, then it is diagonalizable. I can consider now the change of basis $x = R \xi, R \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}, \xi \in \mathbb{R}^n$, with the diagonal matrix $\Lambda = R^T A R$ having the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ of $A$. The polynomial $q$ is then expressed as

$$
q 
= x^T A x + b^T x + c
= \xi^T \Lambda \xi + \beta^T \xi + c
= \left(
\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i \xi_i^2 + \beta_i \xi_i
\right) + c
$$

with $\beta = R^T b$. For $A$, let the last $m$ eigenvalues vanish. We can reformuate $q$ now as

\begin{eqnarray}
q
&=& 
\left(
\sum_{i=1}^{n-m} \lambda_i \xi_i^2 + \beta_i \xi_i
\right) + c
+
\sum_{i=n-m+1}^{n} \beta_i \xi_i
\\
&=&
\left(
\sum_{i=1}^{n-m} \lambda_i \left[\xi_i + \frac{\beta_i}{2 \lambda_i}\right]^2 
\right) 
+ 
\left(
c
-
\sum_{i=1}^{n-m}
\frac{\beta_i^2}{4 \lambda_i}
\right)
+
\sum_{i=n-m+1}^{n} \beta_i \xi_i
\geq 0 \quad \forall \xi
\end{eqnarray}

It is then visible, that the non-vanishing eigenvalues of $A$ have to be positive and that the $b$ have to fulfill $\beta_i = 0 , i \in \{n-m+1,\dots,n\}$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n-m} \beta_i^2/(4\lambda_i) \in [0,c]$ for $0\leq c$. Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 2):

If $b\ne 0$, then 
$p(-cb)=c^2\cdot b^TAb-c\cdot b^Tb\sim -cb^Tb<0$ for small positive $c$, hence $b=0$ is *necessary*.
But if $b=0$, then the desired property id by definition equivalent to $A$ being positive semi-definite.

Comment: hmmm.... crap .... then, there exists no non-negative $p(x)$ with $b \neq 0$ (I just want to make sure, I get this right).

Answer (score 1):

First, note that $A+A^T$ must be positive semi-definite (p.s.d.), since:

$$q(x)=\frac{1}{2} x^T ( A + A^T ) x + b^T x + c,$$

so if $( A + A^T )$ has a negative eigenvalue with corresponding eigenvector $v$, then $q(k v)\rightarrow -\infty$ as $k\rightarrow \infty$.

Given that $( A + A^T )$ is p.s.d., all the stationary points of $q$ are global minima, and if $q$ has no stationary points, then $q$ is unbounded.

Now, the stationary points of $q$ satisfy:

$$0=\frac{d q(x)}{d x} = x^T ( A + A^T ) + b^T$$

i.e.:

$$( A + A^T )x=-b.$$

By the Schur decomposition and the spectral properties of p.s.d. symmetric matrices, there exists an orthogonal matrix $U$ and a diagonal matrix $D$ with weakly positive elements, decreasing in magnitude, such that:

$$A+A^T=U D U^T.$$

Hence:

$$U D U^T x=-b.$$

Now partition $U$ as $U=\begin{bmatrix}U_{\cdot 1} & U_{\cdot 2}\end{bmatrix}$, where the number of columns of $U_{\cdot 1}$ is the same as the number of non-zero elements of $D$. Likewise, partition $D$ as $D=\begin{bmatrix}D_{11} & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$. Then:

$$U_{\cdot 1} D_{11} U_{\cdot 1}^T x=-b.$$

Since $U$ is orthogonal, $U_{\cdot 1}^T U_{\cdot 1}=I$ (as it is the upper left block of $U^T U$) and $U_{\cdot 2}^T U_{\cdot 1}=0$ (as it is the lower left block of $U^T U$). Thus:

$$U_{\cdot 1}^T x=-D_{11}^{-1} U_{\cdot 1}^T b,$$
$$0 = U_{\cdot 2}^T b.$$

If the second condition is violated (e.g. when $q(x,y)=x^2+y$), then there can be no stationary points of $q$, hence $q$ is unbounded (and certainly not always positive). Suppose then that the second condition is satisfied.

Now, as $U$ is full rank, we can find $d,e,y,z$ such that $x=U_{\cdot 1} y + U_{\cdot 2} z$ and $b=U_{\cdot 1} d + U_{\cdot 2} e$. Thus the previous two conditions become:

$$U_{\cdot 1}^T ( U_{\cdot 1} y + U_{\cdot 2} z )=y=-D_{11}^{-1} U_{\cdot 1}^T b,$$
$$0 = U_{\cdot 2}^T (U_{\cdot 1} d + U_{\cdot 2} e) =e,$$

so $z$ is unrestricted, and:

$$y=-D_{11}^{-1} U_{\cdot 1}^T U_{\cdot 1} d=-D_{11}^{-1} d.$$

Finally, to see if $q$ is always positive when $b=U_{\cdot 1} d$, pick an arbitrary $z$ (e.g. $z=0$) and substitute the expression for the stationary point into $q$. If the result is positive then $q$ is always positive. I.e. assuming $b=U_{\cdot 1} d$, $q$ is always positive if and only if:

$$\frac{1}{2} d^T D_{11}^{-1} U_{\cdot 1}^T U_{\cdot 1} D_{11} U_{\cdot 1}^T U_{\cdot 1} D_{11}^{-1} d - d^T U_{\cdot 1}^T U_{\cdot 1} D_{11}^{-1} d + c\ge 0$$

i.e. if and only if:

$$c\ge \frac{1}{2} d^T D_{11}^{-1} d.$$

To conclude then, we have three conditions to check. $q(x)\ge 0$ for all $x$ if and only if:

1. $A+A^T$ is p.s.d..
2. $c\ge \frac{1}{2} b^T U_{\cdot 1} D_{11}^{-1} U_{\cdot 1}^T b$.
3. $0 = U_{\cdot 2}^T b$.

Comment: Cool, thank you very much. But, is there any difference between your conditions at the end and my last edit at the end of my question? If yes, what is the difference?

Comment: Apologies, there was a mistake in the first version of my answer. I had effectively written $1/2-1=0$! Now the conditions are in the same form as yours. (Note that your zero lower bound on $\sum_{i=1}^{n-m} \beta_i^2/(4\lambda_i)$ is not actually a constraint, since the $\lambda$ are positive. Also note that the elements of the diagonal of $D_{11}$ are $2\lambda_i$.) Hopefully, the answer is still of some value as a formal statement of these things.